# Ionic Unkown provider Error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is not a duplicate to any other question asked before about the same problem.
I have tried all the solutions mentioned here and elsewhere, but none of them worked.

I get this error on the browser:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$forceReflowProvider <- $$forceReflow <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24forceReflowProvid…eQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue

I made sure to install `ngAnimate`, to include it in my `index.html`, to call it properly as a dependency, and call it only once, and finally I checked my `bower.json` and updated it.
Anything else I should check?

**UPDATE**

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngRoute', 'starter.homeController', `'starter.clientsController', 'starter.jargonController', 'starter.toolsController', 'starter.welcomeController'])`
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider


    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .state('welcome', {
        url: '/welcome',
        templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
        controller: 'welcomeCtrl',
        css: 'css/welcome.css'
    })

    .state('jargon', {
        url: '/jargon',
        templateUrl: 'templates/jargon.html',
        controller: 'jargonCtrl',
        css: 'css/jarg.css'


    })


    .state('clients', {
        url: '/clients',
        templateUrl: 'templates/clients.html',
        controller: 'clientsCtrl',
        css: 'css/clients.css'


    })


    .state('tools', {
        url: '/tools',
        templateUrl: 'templates/tools.html',
        controller: 'toolsCtrl',
        css: 'css/tools.css'
    });

});
```

HOME:

```
angular.module('starter.homeController', ['ionic', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope){


});
```

Jargon:

```
angular.module('starter.jargonController', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards2', 'ngTouch'])

.controller('jargonCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

WELCOME:

```
angular.module('starter.welcomeController', ['ionic'])
.controller('welcomeCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

TOOLS:

```
angular.module('starter.toolsController', ['ionic'])
.controller('toolsCtrl', function ($scope){

$scope.collapsedd=false;

$scope.toggle=function()
{
    $scope.collapsedd=!$scope.collapsedd;

}
});
```

Comment: This is exclusively an injection issue.  We'd need to see the controller/service/factory that's causing this issue.

Comment: I don't know which one. Ihave many. I ll update my post

Answer (score 0):

Ok So the problem was that angular was not loaded at the right order.
In my index.html, I moved

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

at the top of list of scripts loaded in my application.

Comment: You should not include them both. Either the minified or the non-minified.